# reloading type providers

Tags: visual-studio, f#, type-providers

I am using the MiniCSVTypeProvider provided in the fsharp powerpack samples.

Unfortunately, it thinks the values provided are float, while mine are of various (varying) formats. I therefore rewrote the MiniCsvType provider to always provide strings instead, leaving the parsing work to the caller.

But for some odd reason, after dereferencing the old DLL and including a reference to the new DLL, it kept providing float, using the old type provider. I had to change the names of assembly and classes to have VS refresh it.

Is there any other ways to revoke/reset a former type provider so that VS takes the change into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but encountering the same problem, I solved it by deactivating and reactivating the type provider from Tools -> Options -> F# Tools -> Type providers. (I am using VS2013)

Comment: This options seams to be removed from VS2015. Is it located somewhere else? Or do i need to restart Visual Studio to release a type-provider lock?

Answer (score 7):

In general, when developing a type provider, you'll need to shut down the instance of VS that's consuming a type provider in order to update the provider.  A common workflow is to have two VS instances: one that's working on the code of the type provider itself, which stays open, and another that's referencing/consuming/testing the provider, which you close each time you're going to make a change.  The consumer VS often locks the DLL on disk, and also cannot unload/reload the assembly into its process, which is why you need to end the VS process to iterate on your type provider implementation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great to have that in the *same* Visual Studio ? That would be possible with a notion of 'staged execution' where the level against which you program assumes all deeper level ran before. Deeper level's mission is to provide Types, or variable (aka singleton types) to their next level.